# Creating an indicator for strings of numbers, ignoring a particular one in python pandas

Tags: python, list, pandas, sequence

I have no idea how to title this question, edits welcome.

I have a pandas series of numbers (could be made into a list, the type isn't important really).

The numbers go from 1 to 13.

For example:

```
13,13,1,1,1,1,13,2,1,1
```

I want to find strings of the same numbers but NOT counting `13` if it's in between or at the beginning.

I want to return a new list that is indicator when the `nth` element was either a `13` or the same as the `(n-1)th`.  For example, this would be:

```
 0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1
```

The counter doesn't begin until I observe a non-13, and it then counts 13s as the previous non-13 value.

It also needs to be as fast as possible, so I'd like to avoid crazy loops with a lot of if conditions, if possible.

Comment: According to your rules shouldn't the expected output be: ` 0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1` i.e. an additional 1 at second to last position?

Comment: Anyway does this do what you want: `((s.shift().notnull()) & (s.shift() != 13)).astype(int)`?

Comment: The 1 after the 2 no longer counts because the 2 interrupted the sequences of 1's (ignoring the 13s.)  Another 2 would have resulted in another 1, though.

Comment: Two 13s in a row after a 1 (1,13,13) should give (0,1,1), the code above seems to do (0,1,0)

Comment: It wasn't a strict enough answer, it only appeared to answer your sample data but it evidently didn't, I can't think of a set of conditions that would be able to do this at the moment

Comment: Yeah it's a tough problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 13s at the start are annoying; I can't think of a vectorized way to get rid of them which is efficient.  That said, either of

```
def method1(s):
    out = ((s == s.shift()) | (s == 13)).astype(int)
    for i, x in s.iteritems():
        if x == 13: out[i] = 0
        else: break
    return out

def method2(s):
    s13na = s.replace(13, np.nan).ffill()
    indic = (s13na == s13na.shift()).astype(int)
    return indic
```

should work.  The first method simply asks whether something is equal to the number which came before or 13, and then patches the start.  The second replaces all 13s with `nan`, does a forward-fill (so that the 13s are replaced by the last non-13 number or nan), and then does the usual shift check.  This gives the right answer:

```
>>> method1(s)
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    1
5    1
6    1
7    0
8    0
9    1
dtype: int32
>>> (method1(s) == method2(s)).all()
True
```

Performance will depend on the size of the array and the fraction of 13s..

```
>>> %timeit method1(s)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.13 ms per loop
>>> %timeit method2(s)
1000 loops, best of 3: 704 µs per loop
>>> s2 = pd.concat([s]*100000).reset_index(drop=True)
>>> %timeit method1(s2)
10 loops, best of 3: 75.8 ms per loop
>>> %timeit method2(s2)
1 loops, best of 3: 203 ms per loop
```

Comment: Bravo, you sir, are  a master...!